# Updating .txt file in J2ME located in Binary package

Tags: java-me

I have developed J2ME application that read data from **product.txt** file located in binary package using following code

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/product.txt"); 
int size = is.available();
byte bytes[] = new byte[size];
is.read(bytes, 0, size);
str = new String(bytes, 0, size);
```

Now I want's to update **product.txt** file located in binary package using J2ME code.

I have tried Following code to get relative path of **product.txt**

```
String path=getClass().getResource("/product.txt").getPath();
```

But it does not works on J2ME platform.

How to get relative path Of **product.txt** file located in binary package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change a file that is baked in to the jar.  You'll notice that there is no equivalent of `getResourceAsStream()` that offers an `OutputStream`.

Comment: what is an alternative for it

Comment: Write the file to the filesystem using JSR75, or save the data in RMS.